# Check if id is unique with Karate and not JS or Java

Tags: karate

I would like to check if id is unique in response returned from API request. Is there any way to check this with Karate Intuit and not with JS or Java method called in karate feature.
Ex:

```
Given url baseUrl
And path 'cats'
When method get 
Then status 200
And check if id of each cat is unique
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the creator of Karate, let me say: no there is not.

If we started supporting all of this built-in, it would become a bloated piece of software.

EDIT - now possible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68065532/143475