# Identify uniqueness of JSON attributes

Tags: karate

Running a query I am getting a response like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "row": [
                        {
                            "Name": "name1"
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "row": [
                        {
                            "Name": "name2"
                        }
                    ],

                }
                {
                    "row": [
                        {

                            "Name": "name3"
                        }
                    ],

                }               
                
                
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a best practice recommendation to ensure that "Name" is unique or that row[0] != row [1] != row[2]?

Answer (score 0):

This is 2 lines in Karate 1.1.0.RC3 because `karate.distinct()` is new:

```
* def names = $response..Name
* match names == karate.distinct(names)
```

You can use `contains only` instead of `==` if needed.

So you get the idea. You can use a Java `Set` to make things "unique". Here is a related example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825765/143475